# Laravel + PhpStorm: is it possible jump to function from routes definition in one step?

Tags: laravel, phpstorm

We have quite a lot routes, such as:

```
Route::get('/','WebController@index');
```

When I want to jump to function, I have to:

1. go to the class `WebController`
2. go to the function `index()`

Is it possible jump to function from routes definition in one step?

Comment: You can directly call view in route. Other than that method is same you have to call by using this only Route::get('/','WebController@index'); Or you can us resource route and controller

Comment: install Laravel plugin -- it adds such `Ctrl+Click` navigation. Limitation is -- only within single Router Namespace (e.g. default `app/Http/Controllers` .. or custom one provided in plugin settings).

Answer (score 5):

You should have to install plugin for laravel in php strom.
- Under **Settings** (Preferences) | Plugins, click the Browse repositories... button and search for **Laravel**. 
Next, we can use the Install plugin button or the context menu to proceed with plugin installation.
Restart the IDE to complete the installation of the plugins. Next, we will have to enable the Laravel Plugin in our project. We can do this from Settings (Preferences) | Other Settings | Laravel Plugin | Enable Plugin for this Project. We'll have to restart the IDE once more to load the plugin's additional features for Laravel.
Refrence: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Laravel+Development+using+PhpStorm

Comment: I always forget about the enabling it for the project part, thanks

Comment: For the newer PhpStorm versions (2021.2.2): `Settings > PHP > Laravel > Enable plugin`. Unfortunately searching for this won't work for some reason

Answer (score 3):

You should have to install a plugin for laravel in phpstorm. Go to settings>plugin>marketplace then search Laravel Idea plugin and install but this is paid plugin. You can also, check this URL https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13441-laravel-idea
I think you got your answer after seeing this.

Answer (score 2):

*Because the top answer is outdated and is not accepting edits (queue full) here's the updated version.*

## 2022.3 Update

It seems the [laravel plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7532-laravel/) is no longer updated anymore. The [GitHub repository](https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-laravel-plugin/issues) is also archived.

## 2021 Update

### Tl;dr

Install the laravel plugin and enable it for the current project.

### Steps:

1. Under `Settings | Plugins`, click the `Marketplace` tab at the top and search for "Laravel".
2. Use the Install plugin button to proceed with plugin installation.
3. Restart the IDE to complete the installation of the plugins.
4. Next, Enable the Laravel Plugin in our project. You can find it here:

   `Settings | PHP | Laravel | Enable Plugin for this Project`
5. Restart the IDE once more to load the plugin's additional features for Laravel.

For reference see: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/laravel.html

Comment: You don't need any plugins if you specify the function reference in Callable style:

`Route::get('/', [WebController::class, 'index']);`

It will then work both ways, from controller open the route location and from route you can go to the method directly.

Comment: @pronskiy Thanks, that's good to know! Although, the plugin will, for example, also help with linking view references in controllers to the actual views. It's not mandatory but I prefer to use it

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Laravel Plugin for PHPstorm (Settings -> Plugins -> Laravel)
2. Active it per Project (Settings > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Laravel)
3. Use "Laravel IDE Helper Generator": https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper