# Why PhpStorm recognizes Laravel controller methods as unused?

Tags: php, laravel, phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

I'm using PhpStorm 2019.2.1 to develop Laravel applications. I switched to this version from 9.3 and now it recognizes controller methods and classes as unused. (and provides quick fixes which doesn't help)

What might be the reason for that and how can I solve this?

Comment: It's a new inspection .. and it does not know that certain methods are "actions". Laravel plugin must provide special support for this: see this parent/related issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-47938. ATM I suggest to just disable that inspection either for whole project or for specific folders (see https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-47685#focus=streamItem-27-3610008.0-0)

Comment: Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49645290/laravel-phpstorm-is-it-possible-jump-to-function-from-routes-definition-in-on/65009195#65009195

Answer (score 7):

You can use PHPDoc @uses in your /routes/web.php

```
/**
* @uses App\Http\Controllers\SomeController::SomeMethod
*/

Route::get('/someRoute', 'SomeController@SomeMethod');
```

Answer (score 1):

PhpStorm uses an indexer that looks for calls of your Controller classes and methods, it doesn't recognize the routing second argument because it's a string

```php
Route::get('/someRoute', 'SomeController@SomeMethod');
```

While you can in theory make the controller class and methods static and call them like so

```php
Route::resource('stuff', StuffController::class);
```

and

```php
Route::get('/someRoute', SomeController::SomeMethod);
```

But it's better to either ignore or suppress those warnings